# How do I solve $\int_i^j \frac{1}{\beta}(r^\omega-\alpha^\omega x^\omega)^{1/\omega}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I solve this general form of integral?

$$\int_i^j \frac{1}{\beta}(r^\omega-\alpha^\omega x^\omega)^{1/\omega}\,dx$$

My hope is to find an explicit algebraic expression that's the solution to this integral, such that I can write $r$ as a function of $\alpha,\beta,\omega,i,j$. The values of $i$ and $j$ will always be such that the integral is defined (see context below for justification).

---

Context, for the curious:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g4g9ovt6yw

I made this tool for creating a certain type of shapes, with a constant "radius" $r$. What I mean by this is that the scale of each shape is such that it is exactly contained in the $2r\times 2r$ square centered at the origin. Now I wanted to do the analogous with a constant area (relaxing the square boundary).

Comment: Hint: $y=(x\alpha/r)/\omega$ lets you write this integral as the difference of two incomplete Beta functions.

Comment: If you're interested in computing the areas of the region enclosed by the integrand and its negative, does that mean you're specifically interested in the case $i = - \frac{r}{\alpha}, j = \frac{r}{\alpha}$? As it stands, with arbitrary $i, j$, the question may as well just ask about the indefinite integral.

Comment: Also, are you really interested in the case where the integrand is symmetric about the $y$-axis, so that $x^\omega$ is replaced by $|x|^\omega$? (Of course, that condition is automatic for even $\omega$.)

Comment: @TravisWillse I am not interested in that symmetrical case you have described, as the shape may not present such symmetry. But it would be sufficient to have resolved the case where $i = 0$. And yes, I do suppose it may as well just ask about the indefinite integral...

Comment: I will attempt to solve it on my own using the hint given by @J.G. and will get back with an answer if I reach it

Answer (score 1):

Changing variables to $y = \frac{\alpha}{r} x$ gives the integral
$$\frac{r^2}{\alpha \beta} \int (1 - y^\omega)^\frac{1}{\omega} dy ,$$
and the value of the integral can be expressed in terms of the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) ${}_2 F_1$:
$$\left(\frac{r^2}{\alpha \beta}\right)y \,{}_2 F_1\left(\frac{1}{\omega}, -\frac{1}{\omega}; \frac{\omega + 1}{\omega}; y^\omega\right) + C.$$

For some simple rational values of $\omega$ the function can be written in terms of elementary functions, including:

\begin{array}{cc}
\omega & y \,{}_2 F_1\left(\frac{1}{\omega}, -\frac{1}{\omega}; \frac{\omega + 1}{\omega}; y^\omega\right) \\
\hline
\frac{1}{2} & 2 y^2 - \frac{4}{3} y^{3 / 2} + y \\
1 & \frac{1}{2} y(2 - y) \\
2 & \frac{1}{2} \left(\arcsin y - y \sqrt{1 - y^2}\right) \\
\end{array}

One special case of interest is $i = 0, j = \alpha$:
$$\frac{1}{\beta} \int_0^\alpha (r^\omega-\alpha^\omega x^\omega)^{1/\omega}\,dx = \frac{r^2 \mathrm{B}\left(\frac1\omega, \frac1\omega\right)}{2 \alpha \beta \omega} =\frac{r^2 \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{\omega}\right)^2}{2 \alpha \beta \omega\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{\omega}\right)} ,$$ where $\mathrm{B}, \Gamma$ denote the (complete) beta and gamma functions, respectively. As $\omega \to \infty$, this definite integral is
$$\frac{r^2}{\alpha \beta} \left(1 - \frac{\pi^2}{6 \omega^2} + R(\omega)\right),$$ where $R(\omega) \in O\left(\frac{1}{\omega^3}\right)$.

Comment: Could you add extra steps when determining the new integral on $y$? From my working out, I get the following integral : $\frac{r}{\beta}\int(1-y^\omega)^\frac{1}{\omega}dy$ and I don't see where my mistake is

Comment: @LumpyJumbo  If $y = \frac{\alpha}{r} x$, then $dx = \frac{r}{alpha} dy$. Does that clarify the issue?